# Trying to prove that $\hom\left(\Bbb Z_n , \frac{\mathbb{Q}}{\mathbb{Z}}\right) \cong \Bbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Trying to prove that $$\hom\left(\Bbb Z_n , \frac{\mathbb{Q}}{\mathbb{Z}}\right) \cong \Bbb Z_n$$

So I started out trying to understand when two rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$ and $\frac{r}{s}$ are equivalent mod $\mathbb{Z}$.

$\frac{p}{q} \cong \frac{r}{s} \iff \frac{ps-rq}{qs} \in \mathbb{Z} \iff ps-rq=mqs$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$

but I guess this didn't give me a whole lot of insight. If somebody could explain to me why this is true that would be great! As always multiple perspectives are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, a homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is determined by its value $\varphi(1)$ at $1$. Only restriction is that $n\varphi(1)=0$. For any $0\leq m<n$, the map $1\mapsto m/n+\mathbb{Z}$ gives a homomorphism. I claim that if $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, then it is equivalent to one of the maps $1\mapsto m/n$. Say the order of $\varphi(1)=q+\mathbb{Z}$ is $d$. Then, $d\varphi(1)=0$, i.e. $dq\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $q = m/d$ for some $m$. Write $m=ad+b, 0\leq b<d$, so $m/d+\mathbb{Z}=b/d+\mathbb{Z}$. Write $\frac{b}{d}=\frac{b\frac{n}{d}}{n}$ so we get a number of the form $k/n$, $0\leq k<n$. This shows that every homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $1\mapsto k/n$ for $0\leq k<n$. Moreover, all these maps are indeed distinct since for $k\neq s$, $k/n+\mathbb{Z}=s/n+\mathbb{Z}$ implies $(k-s)/n\in\mathbb{Z}$, which is not possible.

This is how we obtain $n$ different homomorphism. I leave the part where one shows the group of homomorphisms is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to you, you just need to show that $1\mapsto 1/n+\mathbb{Z}$ generates the other maps.

Comment: Another interpretation is the following: Consider the subgroup $G=\{g\in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\mid o(g)\mid n\}$ of all elements whose order divides $n$. This is a subgroup since the group is abelian. The image of any homomorphism $\varphi$ is  necessarily contained in $G$. The computation above shows that $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Then you use the fact that $Hom(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_n)$ is $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply man. Why does getting a number of the form $\frac{k}{n}$ show that every homomorphism has the form $1 \rightarrow \frac{k}{n}$?

Comment: @MutatedPenguin I started with a homomorphism $1\mapsto q$, then I showed that $1\mapsto q$ is the same map as $1\mapsto k/n$. Hence, every homomorphism is of the form $1\mapsto k/n$ for some $0\leq k<n$.

Comment: Hmm... So $\frac{b}{d}=\frac{k}{n}$ and $q=\frac{m}{d}$ so that $\frac{qb}{m}={k}{m}$. I'm still not seeing it, sorry!

Comment: Take the map $1\mapsto q+\mathbb{Z}$. The order of $q+\mathbb{Z}$ divides $n$, so $nq\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence $q=a/n$ for some $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. Use the Euclidean algorithm to write $a=bn+c$ where $0\leq c<n$. Then $q+\mathbb{Z}=a/n+\mathbb{Z}=c/n+\mathbb{Z}$.